# Antd: I'm trying to change the default styling of Antd's checkboxes using styled components to make the checkbox larger and change the color to black

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, styled-components, antd

I have an Antd checkbox that I'm trying to make larger, alter the thickness of the box itself and change the color to black but every style I apply creates a second square that sits over the checkbox and doesn't change the checkbox itself. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have you added `appearance: none;` to ensure the browser default isn't rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out by using `&&&{border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black}` the triple ampersand allows you to add more specificity when working with mixed styled components like mine.